# How do I get a lambda query that is like this tsql query?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, t-sql, group-by

Having a T-SQL query:

```
select [ProductNumber] ,max([ProductRevNumber])
from Products  
group by [ProductNumber]
```

Attempted LINQ query:

```
ProductsDBContext.Products.GroupBy(x => x.ProductRevNumber)
                          .Select(group => ProductNumber, 
                                           ProductRevNumber = group.Max(x => x.ProductRevNumber));
```

The lambda query doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is what you are after:

```
var latestProducts = ProductsDBContext.Products
    .GroupBy(p => p.ProductNumber).Select(g => new 
    {
        ProductNumber = g.Key,
        MaxProductRevNumber = g.Max(p => p.ProductRevNumber))
    });
```

Comment: What does g.Key represent? Is it a special keyword or some sort?

Comment: g.Key is the value of the field you grouped on (i.e. p.ProductNumber).

Answer (score 2):

```
from p in db.Products
group p by p.ProductNumber into g
select new
{
    ProductNumber = g.Key,
    ProductRevNumber = g.Max(p => p.ProductRevNumber)
};
```